# MySQL: Can't update table 'orders' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `orders` in a MySQL database.  The `payment_date` attribute is Null until we receive the funds, at which point it's updated with a date.  Once the `payment_date` attribute is updated the `order_state` attribute is updated (manually!) from a value of ***either*** 1 or 2 to a value of 3.

I'd like to create a **trigger** to automate this flow.  Here's my attempt:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER update_order_state

AFTER UPDATE
ON orders FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF ( NEW.payment_date IS NOT NULL AND NEW.order_state IN (1, 2) )
        THEN
        UPDATE orders SET order_state = 3 WHERE NEW.payment_date IS NOT NULL and NEW.order_state IN (1, 2);
    END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

When I invoke this, I get the following error message:

`[HY000][1442] Can't update table 'orders' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`

Thinking that this could be a case of locking (or risk of an infinite loop), I changed the trigger to `BEFORE UPDATE`.  But, I get the same error message.

How would I work around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to update only the row(s) that spawned the trigger, or are you trying to update other rows in the table that match the same conditions, even if those rows were not updated?

Comment: I'm only trying to update the row(s) that spawned the trigger (e.g. if someone populates a `payment_date` in rows 7 and 8, then the `order_status` in rows 7 and 8 would switch from, say, 1 to 3 (or from 2 to 3, depending on the situation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, given you commented above that you only need to update the rows that spawned the trigger, you can do that without using `UPDATE` in the body of the trigger.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER update_order_state
BEFORE UPDATE
ON orders FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF ( NEW.payment_date IS NOT NULL AND NEW.order_state IN (1, 2) )
        THEN
        SET NEW.order_state = 3;
    END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Setting `NEW.<column>` only applies to the respective row that spawned the trigger.

The trigger body processes one row at a time, indicated by `FOR EACH ROW`. So if the `UPDATE` action that spawned this trigger involves multiple rows, they will each be processed one at a time.

Changing any value of `NEW.<column>` requires that you use a `BEFORE` trigger. Once the `AFTER` trigger runs, it's too late to change any values.